# Creating new node based on detection of grand-child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Can anyone help me out on my below requirement. 
If publisher/catalogue/cd11/year is available/exist then a new element with value need to created as publisher/catalogue/cd22 = 'New Release'

Thanks, in advance

INPUT XML:

```
<publisher>
    <Name id="d123">
        <Location>Chicago</Location>
    </Name>
    <catalogue id="d1" >
        <cd11 id="d2">
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd11>
    </catalogue>
    <catalogue id="d3" >
        <cd11 id="d4">
            <title>Jurassic World</title>
            <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
        </cd11>
    </catalogue>    
</publisher>
```

Transform: `<cd22>New Release</cd22>` should be created if 'year' element is existed in publisher/catalogue/cd11 path

OUTPUT XML:

```
<publisher>
    <Name id="d123">
        <Location>Chicago</Location>
    </Name>
    <catalogue id="d1" >
        <cd11 id="d2">
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd11>
        <cd22>New Release</cd22>
    </catalogue>
    <catalogue id="d3" >
        <cd11 id="d4">
            <title>Jurassic World</title>
            <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
        </cd11>
    </catalogue>    
</publisher>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copying) and then override (match) all `catalogue` elements that have a descendant `cd11/year`.

In my example, I check to see if `year` is not empty, but you can change this if it matters.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalogue[string(cd11/year)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <cd22>New Release</cd22>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @GJ_15 - You're very welcome. Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark to the left.